# What is the VSTS Link Settings feature?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am talking about this:

[image]

The documentation I found is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/parameters?view=vsts, but I must be plain stupid, because I do not understand one bit of it.

I do not know why it is so hard, but I cannot find anything meaningful on the web.

We have an on-premises TFS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have a build configuration ("Release") that you want to use in conjunction with multiple instances of the `Visual Studio Build` task.

You could add a variable called `BuildConfiguration` and then put the value `$(BuildConfiguration)` in the "Configuration" box for all of your Visual Studio Build tasks.

Or, you could enter the actual value, "Release", and then link the Configuration field in Visual Studio build to a pipeline parameter. Then you can manage the value from the "Pipeline" view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this online azure-devops? Because I do not have Pipeline in my Web Interface (we use on-premises TFS). Also, I tend to keep my build steps to a bare minimum and utilize a build script instead in order to enjoy all the benefits of the Version Control. Do Link Settings apply in this case?

Comment: @mark It should be. On-prem TFS uses slightly different terminology. The "pipeline" features can be found under the "Build and Release" section.

Comment: But is it relevant when the whole process is basically one step?

Comment: @mark Not really. If you don't need to use it, don't use it.